# Regular expressions in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regex pattern to match this format `ABC12345678`:

it should start with ABC and should have preceding 8 numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for is

```
ABC\d{8}
```

Comment: You might want to anchor the regex: `^ABC\d{8}$`, otherwise, depending on how the regex is used, it may match strings like `ABC123456789101112...`.

Comment: @Bart K. +1, that might definitely be the case, depending on the desired result, which isn't very well defined.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have to write a regex (which I try to avoid as much as possible), I refer to [this .NET regex cheat sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx).

Comment: Why do you avoid regular expressions?

Comment: Because a) I'm not good at them, and b) many times there's a better solution.  I'm not saying they shouldn't be used, or are never applicable, I'm just describing my behavior.

Answer (score 0):

[txt2re](http://txt2re.com/) is a great online resource for creating regex from a string. It also generates code samples in many languages including c#.